# Weaker form of inverse Galois problem

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-extensions

I do not know if this correct. So I ask.

Given a number $n\geq 2$, can we find a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$ such that the group has order $n$? Similarly, given $n\in \mathbb N$ can we find a totally imaginary number field that is a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$ and for which the order of its Galois group is $2n$?

Comment: This seems like a weaker form to me.

Comment: Oh is it. Ok I'm sorry. Feel free to correct if you know better. I was trying to figure if it should be "stronger" or "weaker". I am not confident. So please correct if you think the title of the question needs to be corrected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are correct: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53708/precise-definition-of-weaker-and-stronger

Comment: According to [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2204162/110831), there is always a real and cyclic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ (for any $n\geq 2$).  To get a totally imaginary extension of degree $2n$, simply add a square root of $-1$.

Comment: The inverse Galois problem for abelian groups/extensions is much easier because we can deal with cyclotomic extensions.

Comment: Pierre-Guy I think your answer is valid and I would gladly mark it as an answer if you put it in as answer instead of comment! Thanks!

Comment: @Arthur I changed the title from "Stronger" to "Weaker". I think you are right. Thanks