# Do there exist $2k+1$ irrational numbers such that their product and sum are both rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I recently found a problem saying "Find 2 irrational numbers such that their sum and product is both rational."

After a while I noticed any pair like $(a+\sqrt{b},a-\sqrt{b})$ work .From this I could easily say this statement is true for any even integer.But then I thought whether the same is true for odd integers.
I realized proving it for $3$ would imply the statement being true for all odd integers.
I tried to work with similar expression as above.I also tried to work with the cubic polynomial.But I couldn't make any significant progress.

Comment: Take any polynomial of odd degree with no rational roots, like  $x^3-5x^2+3x+2$.  That one has real roots (not sure you wanted to require that).  the product of the roots is $-2$ and the sum is $5$.  A similar approach works for any degree.

Comment: How to make sure that all its roots are real?

Comment: I just adjusted the constant to get something that works.

Comment: To prove existence in general, it's probably easiest to use some Galois theory.  See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867852/totally-real-galois-extension-of-given-degree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take $\{j\:\sqrt[2k+1]{2}|1\le j\le 2k\}\cup\{-k(2k+1)\:\sqrt[2k+1]{2}\}$. The sum is $0$; the product is $-(2k+1)!2k$.